# android SharedPreferences apply() race condition

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

According to the android developer reference, the apply() method will

> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures.

It is clear that apply() is an async call, which means work in another thread. However I'd like to know if the apply() method is susceptible to a race condition?

Comment: I never use commit() and apply() works fine for me till date. However, you can avoid apply() where you are writing to storage and reading it in the next line of command.

Comment: `SharedPreferences` is `synchronised` using `apply()` if you use ONE `SharedPreferences.Editor`,  however is NOT if you use TWO instances of `SharedPreferences.Editor` and call `apply()` on both.  That is, to be synchronised whilst editing the same values (calling `editor.apply()` twice) use the same editor instance - I'll assume each editor instance has a queue.

Comment: @MarkKeen Where do you find that the methods are `synchronized`? Looking at the source code at [here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/SharedPreferences.java), it appears that none of the methods have the `synchronized` keyword

Comment: If you read the docs it's Atomic